# Capitalize specific character from HashMap String

Tags: java, arrays, string, split, hashmap

I have a program which converts numbers 0-9 in a `String` to their text equivalents (e.g: "0" becomes "zero"). However, when the number is at the beginning of the sentence I need to capitalize it.

**Example**

```
4 dogs were chasing 3 cats.
The 8 eggs were separated into 3 groups.
```

Becomes:

```
four dogs were chasing three cats.
The eight eggs were separated into three groups.
```

**Code**

```
public String ConvertSentance(String s){
    sb = new StringBuilder();

    h.put("0","zero");
    h.put("1","one");
    h.put("2", "two");
    h.put("3", "three");
    h.put("4", "four");
    h.put("5", "five");
    h.put("6", "six");
    h.put("7", "seven");
    h.put("8", "eight");
    h.put("9", "nine");

    String[] split = s.split(" ");

    for (String newS : split) {
        if (h.containsKey(newS)) {
            sb.append(h.get(newS));
            sb.append(' ');
        }
        else {
            sb.append(newS);
            sb.append(' ');
        }
    }

    convertedSent = sb.toString();
    return sb.toString();

}
```

How could I get this to capitalize the beginning character so that the output turns into this?

```
Four dogs were chasing three cats.
```

I am having trouble getting this to work only when they number is at the beginning of the sentence. I have tried different variations of `for-loops` with no success.

Comment: `return convertedSent.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + convertedSent.substring(1);` to capitalize the first character of your string

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you should use a simple parser. What do i mean? You should define when new sentence begins (after appearing `'.'`,`'?'`,`'!'`, next word will begin from capitalized letter). You can use simple boolean field `sentenceEnded` which is true when `newS` ends with one of those symbols, and becomes false after next word. When you do it, you could use this code sample to do what you want:

```
if (sentenceEnded) {
    String token = h.get(newS);
    sb.append((char) ('A' + token.charAt(0) - 'a')); //dirty hack; dont use it in real projects
    sb.append(token.substring(1, token.length()));
}
```

Comment: why not use `String.toUpperCase()`?

Comment: Because `char` has no `toUpperCase()` method ;)

Comment: I meant `token.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()`. Why do you think your hack is better?

Comment: I dont think my hack is better. Both approaches are acceptable.

Comment: Upvoted, not because of the hack ;) But it's a good answer anyway.